# need an idea for a problem about saving player on a list discord.py bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I made a truth or dare bot which start with --start command and get a list of all players who are already joined on a voice channel and randomly mention one of them. everything work properly but there is only one problem that im facing with. The problem is that when bot store all players from a voice channel on a server and save it in an empty list[] when bot get started in other servers the name of the players on that server save on the list as well so it mentions players from other servers too.

for ex. bot started in server named x: playerlist[a,b,c]

and in the meanwhile bot started in server name y: playerlist[a,b,c,d,e,f]
it actually should be playerlist[d,e,f] in y server

Can anybody give me an idea about how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary like so:

```py
{
  server1_id: [
    user1,
    user2,
    user3,
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: can I use rand to use one of that users in the values randomly?

Comment: @SAMANMOKHTARI Yes, just make sure to select the right list from the dictionary: `choice(myDict[server1_id])`, not `choice(myDict)`. Remember to upvote and accept my answer if it's helpful. :)